# sql and python cant get the name out of the result

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

I was using sqllite3 in my python code and I did this

```
name = db.execute("SELECT username FROM names WHERE username = ....")
```

and I got this back

```
[{'username': 'name'}]
```

and for a reason I cant get that name out by anyway

so my question is how to get the name out

```
db.execute("SELECT username FROM names WHERE username = ....")
```

and I was expecting a name only

Comment: What have you tried? You seem to have a gap in your Python fundamentals - you may benefit from an introductory tutorial on Python and its data structures, namely `list`s and `dict`s, if this lexicon with square `[]` and curly braces `{}` is foreign to you.

Comment: Is `name[0]['username']` what you are looking for?

Comment: SQL select statements can potentially have many rows of results, so python returns the output as a list.  If you know your result will only have one row, then just access the first list item using `[0]`.

Comment: `name[0]` works here, but it will throw an exception if the query doesn't return a user. Learning the basics about Python data structures is fundamental.

Comment: `name = db.execute("SELECT username FROM names WHERE username = ....")` - make sure you read up on SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3.execute()` returns a `list` of `dict`s, with each `dict` representing a row that was returned by the query. You can use bracket notation followed by dot notation to get the property value you're after from within the object at index `0`:

```
print(name[0]['username']) # "name"
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/JuvenileStainedDeal#main.py)